# After partition tool GParted take a screen snapshot, where is the file located?

Tags: debian, partitioning, gparted

After partition tool GParted is done with the partitioning, I looked at the details and the further details of each action by clicking on them.

To save it as a record, I took 2 screen snapshots too (using the Screenshot tool), and it is said to be stored on /root.  So after that, I reboot to Win7 (or can reboot to Ubuntu 9.04).

At this point, where can the files be located, as /root was there when GParted was running with Debian.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GParted is a boot CD, so its file-system is local and resides in memory, and is lost after it terminates.

You must save the screenshots on a real disk.

I quote from [HOWTO backup any output from the livecd](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=191):

Open a terminal from the panel, by clicking the terminal icon and then type the following :

> fdisk -ul > myfile.txt

plug your usb key and type :

> fdisk -l | grep sd*

search for your just plugged key : it could be something like sda1, or if you have sata or scsi hard disk, it could be sdb1 or even sdc1... try to guess : may be you could unplug your key and run the "fdisk -l" command again to see the differences...
Imagine your key is plugged on sdb1, then type :

> mkdir /tmp/usb
>   mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp/usb
>  cp
>   myfile.txt /tmp/usb
>  ls /tmp/usb
>   (there you MUST see myfile.txt !)
>   umount /tmp/usb

unplug your key and plug it on your pc (after you have booted your OS), to get the file.

Comment: To add to that: the screen captures the question asker created have been lost. But I guess one can start GParted again, just to view the current settings, and then make new screen captures.